# sqlite syntax error with hex function

Tags: sqlite

I wanted to select the 1st row of the table X below and update the column "name" to '53656C696E613333' as shown below. Sqlite keeps saying syntax error. Can someone please assist with this problem? Many thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE Ages (name VARCHAR(128),age INTEGER)`

DELETE FROM Ages;
INSERT INTO Ages (name,age) Values ('Alex',25);
INSERT INTO Ages (name,age) Values ('Mel',31);
INSERT INTO Ages (name,age) Values ('Fred',30);
INSERT INTO Ages (name,age) Values ('Nancy',35);
INSERT INTO Ages (name,age) Values ('Nathan',13);
INSERT INTO Ages (name,age) Values ('Oscar',24);

SELECT hex (name||age) AS X FROM Ages ORDER BY X

SELECT * FROM X LIMIT 1
UPDATE X SET name = '53656C696E613333'
```

Comment: There is no table `X` anywhere, just an `X` alias for the `hex(name || age)` result in the previous SELECT. Are you trying to update `Ages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be wanting something like :-

```
UPDATE Ages 
    SET name = '53656C696E613333' 
    WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM Ages ORDER BY hex(name||age) LIMIT(1))
        AND age = (SELECT age FROM Ages ORDER BY hex(name||age) LIMIT(1))
;
```

as a replacement for :-

```
SELECT hex (name||age) AS X FROM Ages ORDER BY X

SELECT * FROM X LIMIT 1
UPDATE X SET name = '53656C696E613333'
```

This would result in :-

[image]

However, as you haven't specified `WITHOUT ROWID` for the table, then you could use the simpler :-

```
UPDATE Ages 
    SET name = '53656C696E613333' 
    WHERE rowid = (SELECT rowid FROM Ages ORDER BY hex(name||age) LIMIT(1))
;
```